# How can I implement triple buffering using Direct3D 9?

Tags: c#, c++, directx9, vsync, double-buffering

I am creating an application using Direct3D 9. I want to implement triple buffering with vsync. I can successfully create a graphics device object with 2 back buffers. How do I know which buffer to draw to?

EDIT:

Here is how I retrieve a pointer to the back buffer onto which I will draw using a deferred shading technique:

```
// graphics device object
IDirect3DDevice9 *pd3dDevice = GetDevice();

// back buffer pointer
IDirect3DSurface9 *pBackBuffer = null;

// get pointer to back buffer
pd3dDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 1, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackBuffer);
```

UPDATE:
The application appears to run faster when I use a pointer to the first back buffer like so:

```
// graphics device object
IDirect3DDevice9 *pd3dDevice = GetDevice();

// back buffer pointer
IDirect3DSurface9 *pBackBuffer = null;

// get pointer to back buffer --- NOTICE THE Back Buffer Index parameter is now 0 ---
pd3dDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackBuffer);
```

When using the back buffer at index 1 the frame rate falls to 30fps while using vsync. This produces artifacts and Horizontal Shearing. Using the back buffer at index 0 seems to be correct. When using this buffer the application presents a frame at the refresh rate of the monitor. Therefore in order to correctly implement triple buffering using Direct3D 9 you should draw to the back buffer at index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know which buffer to draw to?

You don't.  Direct3D will automatically manage this for you and correctly rotate the back buffers at Present time.

Comment: I implement deferred shading in my application...retrieving a pointer to the back buffer (onto which I will draw ) is necessary. Do I simply get a pointer to the '2nd' back buffer? See code above...

Comment: So long as you make this call each frame you will get the correct backbuffer - whichever one is current.  You shouldn't expect it to be correct if you reuse the same pointer over multiple frames.